# Units on the graph editor

Tags: animation, graph-editor

So below I have a quick animation.

Notice that I have the units set to meters ( yellow arrow ) and when you look on the graph editor ( red arrow ) these units are represented perfectly and you can (G) + (Y) + (value in meters) move these points around just like in the main viewport.

[image: Step right up and prove you graph editor knowledge :)]

However if I change my world units to inches the change is shown on the viewport location values ( green arrow ) but the graph editor values ( pink arrow ) DO NOT change.

[image]

How can we sync these up? Is it possible?

Thank you everyone!!

Comment: Seems like blender haven't support imperial units in graph

Comment: bummer :(

I know the imperial system is not great but still ... 

Thank you for the reply RUben!